# Repopulating form with TWIG and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig, codeigniter-form-helper

I want to repopulate my form if there's something wrong.

In normal Codigniter I would use:

```
<input value"<?php set_value('name_of_field');>">
```

But plain PHP is not working in .twig files.

Any best-practices for this?

Thank you!

Stijn

Comment: In CodeIgniter, you have Form Helper which allows to use `set_value()` but in other case, you cannot do like that. You can read more here [link](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc3.x-php5/examples/html5.php)

Comment: I know, but I can't use it with TWIG templating. How can I repopulate my form?